# Specifying a constraint for a class

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have three data declarations in the different modules:

```hs
data Data1 = Data1
  { id :: UUID
  , field2 :: String
  , field3 :: Int
  }

data Data2 = Data2
  { id :: UUID
  , field1112 :: String
  , field4433 :: String
  }


data Data3 = Data3
  { id :: UUID
  , field22 :: Double
  , field344 :: Int
  }
```

And a class declaration:

```hs
class MyClass1 a where
  method1 ....
```

How can I specify a constraint for `MyClass1` so that only `Data1, Data2 and Data3` can be instantiated by `MyClass1` because they **all have the field `id`**?
I tried the following, but it didn't seem right to me and I got errors:

```
-- in the different module
class MyDataBase a where
  id :: a -> UUID

-- in the module Data1.hs
instance MyDataBase Data1 where
  id d1 =  

-- in the module Data2.hs
-- and so on....


class (MyDataBase a) => MyClass1 a where
  method1 .... = -- calling
```

Comment: "I got errors:" - what errors

Comment: it's just my 50cts. but this seems to be to OO for my taste - there might be a different problem lurking in the background which should be taken care of. Anway this really reminds me of [this Antipattern](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) - maybe you find the article (and the alternatives there) interesting

Comment: Your approach should work, although you will have to be a bit careful since you have five different identifiers named `id` (the three from Data1, Data2, Data3, the class method of MyDataBase, and the one from Prelude).

Answer (score 4):

> so that only Data1, Data2 and Data3 can be instantiated by MyClass1 because they all have the field id?

What about types you don't know about that also have that field?

In general, you can accomplish things like that with Lens (regular Haskell records are IMHO unusable); if you name your fields `_Data1Id` and `_Data2Id` (customizable), you'll get a `HasId` class with `id` lens and instances for that class for `Data1` and `Data2`. Then you can use that class as a constraint further.

Of course you don't have to use `makeFields` and you can write the instances yourself. Not sure why you'd do that, though.

---

You didn't specify what errors you got, but I bumped off `UndecidableInstances`. Here's how to get around "Constraint is no smaller than the instance head" error:

```
class A a where aOp :: a -> Int
class B a where bOp :: a -> Int

data C = forall a. B a => C a
instance A C where aOp (C a) = bOp a
```

This will allow you to use any type that satisifies B in a A context (but as Carsten pointed out, it's also an antipattern of sorts).

Comment: **What about types you don't know about that also have that field?** - the same thing.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your answer, it's too much vague.

Comment: @jawanam For what it's worth, I don't understand your question for the exact same reason.

Comment: @DanielWagner, what's it got to do with you?

Comment: @jawanam If you poke around, you will find I am one of the most active users answering questions in the haskell tag. So "what it's got to do with me" is that questions I understand often get high quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do that. The simplest way of achieving what you want is the following:

```
class HasId a where
    getId :: a -> UUID

class HasId a => MyClass1 a where
    method1 =   -- NOTE: Use "getId" instead of plain "id".
```

when you define your data types you simply do:

```
data Data1 = Data1
    { id :: UUID
    , field2 :: String
    , field3 :: Int
    }

instance HasId Data1 where
    getId = id
```

If you want to add a new data type to the family you simply create a new instance of the `HasId` class.

You don't need no extensions, nothing fancy, no libraries. Sure you can probably shorten the code or do something more fancy, but I'd prefer to use simple code that works and I understand versus code that I don't understand.

Comment: That's great. Is there any way to avoid redundancy in using "getId" and "id" to use only "id"?

Comment: Yes, and this is what my answer presents. If you Google `makeFields` you should be able to find examples without a problem. This approach has one significant drawback at the cost of "simplicity": `HasId` can now only be used to *read* data, you can't update a field with it. If you tried to write proper lenses yourself it would OTOH get more lengthy and complicated.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, your answer focuses on the libraries instead of fundamentals. What would you do if Lens didn't exist?

Comment: What would you do if Haskell didn't exist? I told you, you can write your own lenses for everything, there's hardly any magic in `makeFields` besides boilerplate removal. We thankfully live in a world where Lens DOES exist and I see no reasons to not use it.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, to be able to apply Lens one has to know what's behind Lens **first** and how accomplish the same thing without using Lens.